# Why is "double" represented as integer?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, double, binary-data

```
void foo(double a) {  
  ...
}
```

And in `main()` I passed `107.0` to `foo` as its parameter. Then I used gdb to examine the binary representation of `a` by `p /t a`, and this is what I got:

```
$1 = 1101011
```

This results seems very strange to me. This is the binary representation of INTEGER 107. But here the type of `a` is defined as `double` and we passed a parameter of `107.0`. And we know that doubles have different binary representations as integers.

Can anyone explain why `a` has a integer binary rep rather than double? Is the compiler doing anything funny?

Comment: `/t` doesn't mean printing the bit pattern, it just means a base 2 representation of the value, the value itself being 107 (gdb knows the type of your `a`). To find out the bit pattern, use the `x` command.

Answer (score 5):

You told gdb to print it as a binary integer.

```
 p /t a
```

If you want to see the floating point version use

```
 p /f a
```

[Output formats](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC55)

> x Regard the bits of the value as an integer, and print the integer in
>   hexadecimal.
>
> d Print as integer in signed decimal.
>
> u Print as integer in unsigned decimal.
>
> o Print as integer in octal.
>
> t Print as integer in binary. The letter `t' stands for "two". (2)
>
> a Print as an address, both absolute in hexadecimal and as an offset
>   from the nearest preceding symbol. You can use this format used to
>   discover where (in what function) an unknown address is located:
>
> c Regard as an integer and print it as a character constant.
>
> f Regard the bits of the value as a floating point number and print
>   using typical floating point syntax.
>
> For example, to print the program counter in hex (see section
>   Registers), type `p/x $pc`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I was using `p /t a` actually. But in any case, the format specifier is `\t`, which tells it to print as binary. So the original typo'ed `d` only serves as a variable name.

Comment: @OneZero web page says it should be a forward slash  For example, to print the program counter in hex (see section Registers), type

`p/x $pc`

Answer (score 1):

Doubles are represented in powers of two, just a bit different than integers. Not going into much details, 107 would be 1.101011 * (2^6) = 1101011. It is possible that gdb only shows the last result instead of giving you the full 64bit representation for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to print variables' values from the gdb command line.

- [print](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC52) works on expressions, and will do some implicit conversions, just as C does.

  `p /t a` in your example will convert a's value to an integer and print it in base 2.

  You wanted to look at `a`'s bit pattern, so there are a few options with `print`:

  - you can cast its address to a pointer to an unsigned integer type that's the same length as a double - probably `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t` in your example - and dereference that.

    `(gdb) p /t *(uint64_t *)&a`

    `$6 = 100000001011010110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
  - You can use `{uint64_t}` to accomplish the same thing more concisely.

    `(gdb) p /t {uint64_t}&a`

    `$7 = 100000001011010110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
- [x](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC56) displays the data at a given address, and you can specify the datatype. `/g` means an 8-byte integer.

  `(gdb) x /tg &a`

  `0x7fffffffded8: 0100000001011010110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

If you use optimization, it's possible that `a` will be in a register, and you won't be able to take its address, so none of the above will work.

```
(gdb) p {uint64_t}&a
Address requested for identifier "a" which is in register $ymm0
```

But `gdb` supports printing the contents of AVX registers in various formats, using syntax resembling a C union of arrays.

```
(gdb) p $ymm0
$1 = {v8_float = {0, 3.41796875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
v4_double = {107, 0, 0, 0}, v32_int8 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -64, 90, 
64, 0 <repeats 24 times>},
v16_int16 = {0, 0, -16384, 16474, 0 <repeats 12 times>},
v8_int32 = {0, 1079689216, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
v4_int64 = {4637229872563879936, 0, 0, 0},
v2_int128 = {0x0000000000000000405ac00000000000, 0x00000000000000000000000000000000}}

(gdb) p /t $ymm0.v4_int64[0]
$2 = 100000001011010110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

well im not familiar with gdb, but when you write "d" it might think that you explicitly mean integers

consider:

```
double foo = 1.0;
printf("%d",foo);
```

c will be confused because you tell it you will give it an integer but you  actually give it a double.